# ReactiveUI Validate only when user input changes

Tags: validation, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm a newbie to a ReactiveUI, so I stuck with the issue, that my error messages are displayed on the Page Start, not after the user input changes.

I suppose I have an issue with ComplexRule.
So here is my code in ViewModel:

```
    public LoginViewModel(IScreen screen)
    {
        HostScreen = screen;
        NameRule = this.ValidationRule(
            viewModel => viewModel.UserName,
            name => name.Length > 2,
            "You must specify a valid name longer then 2 sybols.");

        //checks with Regexp password
        PasswordRule = this.ValidationRule(
            viewModel => viewModel.Password,
            password => PasswordValidator.Validate(password),
            "You must specify a valid password longer then 8 sybols with at least 1 digit, upper 
             case, lower case and special characters.");

        var nameAndPasswordRules = this
            .WhenAnyValue(
                x => x.UserName,
                x => x.Password,
                (name, password) => NameRule.IsValid && PasswordRule.IsValid);

        ComplexRule = this.ValidationRule(
            _ => nameAndPasswordRules,
            (vm, state) => !state ? "Username and Password should be both valid!" : string.Empty);

        var canNavigate = this.IsValid();

        NavigateToMainPage = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() =>
        {
            return HostScreen.Router.NavigateAndReset.Execute(new MyTabbedViewModel(HostScreen));
        }, canNavigate);
    }
```

And here is my View:

```
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.UserName, v => v.username.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.BindValidation(ViewModel, vm => vm.NameRule, v => v.usernameErrors.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Password, v => v.password.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.BindValidation(ViewModel, vm => vm.PasswordRule, v => v.passwordErrors.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);

            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.NavigateToMainPage, x => x.loginButton)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
    }
```

So I'm trying to achieve validation after user input changes (password / username) and show appropriate message. 
I took this example from documentation.

Comment: Username and Password properties are marked with [Reactive] attribute

`'
  [Reactive]
  public string UserName { get; set; } = String.Empty;

  [Reactive]
  public string Password { get; set; } = String.Empty;
`'

Comment: The Fody stuff means I can't be much help  - I do mine manually - but there is a `DistinctUntilChanged` operator which might be of use to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work as it can't Distinct between null and not null element.
So I have done it in a different way. Not sure what is the best practice here(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying a couple of approaches and finished with this one.
Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it works(
Would like to hear your opinion, if you know how to do it better.

I assign `null` value to a properties

```
[Reactive]
public string UserName { get; set; } = null;

[Reactive]
public string Password { get; set; } = null;
```

so we would assume that null - means it was never used.

And put such validation on the ValidationRule

```
        var name = this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.UserName)
            .Select(x => x == null || x?.Length > 2);

        var password = this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.Password)
            .Select(x => x == null || PasswordValidator.Validate(x));

        var nameAndPasswordRules = this
            .WhenAnyValue(
                x => x.UserName,
                x => x.Password)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .SkipWhile(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Item1) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Item2))
            .Select(prop1 =>
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop1.Item1)
                        && this.NameRule.IsValid
                        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop1.Item2)
                        && this.PasswordRule.IsValid);

        NameRule = this.ValidationRule(
            _ => name,
            (vm, state) => !state ? "You must specify a valid name longer then 2 sybols." : string.Empty);

        PasswordRule = this.ValidationRule(
            _ => password,
            (vm, state) => !state ? "You must specify a valid password longer then 8 sybols with at least 1 digit, upper case, lower case and special characters." : string.Empty);

        ComplexRule = this.ValidationRule(
            _ => nameAndPasswordRules,
            (vm, state) => !state ? "Username and Password should be both valid!" : string.Empty);
```

As you can see, I do `x == null || ...`
Means to bypass first try, because user haven't edited the Entry

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark your answer after three days. It will help others who have similar issue.